# dfsutil works in CMD but not in PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I'm facing the problem that a command in CMD doesn't work in PowerShell but it works in CMD.

The command I've tried:

`dfsutil property SD grant \\domain\group "domain\SecurityGroup1:RX"`

If I do it with the same permissions in CMD it works, but if I do it in PowerShell it doesn't affect.

I also have tried this:

`cmd.exe /c "dfsutil property SD grant \\domain\group "domain\SecurityGroup1:RX""`

Same problem

Can somebody help me?

Comment: replace double quotes with single qoutes 'domain\SecurityGroup1:RX'

Comment: PowerShell can run commands just fine, so we need to know what "doesn't work" means: What error are you getting? Does the account from which you are running the command have sufficient permissions?

Comment: or replace outer double quotes with single qoutes  'dfsutil..."domain\SecurityGroup1:RX"'

Comment: I've tried it with single quotes, but the same problem. I don't get any error. Powershell tells me: "Done processing this command."

Comment: Also it doesn't work when I try with outer single and inner double quotes.

Comment: [Related](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/dfscmds.shtml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! Finally....

`$DFSroot = "\\sub.domain.com\group\folder"
 $DFScmd = '"domain\Domain Admins:RX"''
 Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\system32\dfsutil.exe" -ArgumentList "property SD grant $DFSroot $DFScmd protect"`

Answer (score 0):

```
.\dfsutil property SD grant \\domain\group "domain\SecurityGroup1:RX"
```

Try it like that maybe? I am not sure why that would matter but found reference to it on this page:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/ae8da772-a434-4ae4-9004-42d5730b78f8/cant-use-dfsutil-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Are you running powershell as an administrator? On my copy of windows 7 it is recognizing dfsutil as a powershell command. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Yes I run PowerShell with the same permissions like I run CMD (Domain Admin)

Comment: I don't get any error. Powershell tells me: "Done processing this command."

Comment: try this:

.\dfsutil property SD grant \\domain\group "domain\SecurityGroup1":RX

Comment: without the .\

so just the :RX outside of the quotes

Comment: If I put :RX outside the command, I get the dfsutil /? as an answer.

Comment: hmm

dfsutil property SD grant \\domain\group domain\SecurityGroup1:RX

Maybe try without the quotes, I don't think they are needed unless there is a space in the name of the Group. I assume you are replacing domain with the actual name of your domain as well.. aside from that I am noticing that typically for replacing the permissions you might need to specify::: dfsutil property SD grant \\domain\group domain\SecurityGroup1:RX protect replace :::: protect replace, or at least replace, if these are replacing other permissions. that would explain why it wanted you to do a /? for more option

Comment: I've tried this right now as well... I'm so frustrated, working on this since 4 hours... I don't see anything... what makes me think is why it works in CMD and not in PS?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2938148/the-windows-powershell-cmdlet-grant-dfsnaccess-does-not-change-inherit :::: try that link, could it be due to the inheritence? That post says so specify protect behind your command, or to change the inheritence

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so but maybe an important fact is that the DFS is in a subdomain of the domain where the groups are located so ist like this:

`.\dfsutil property SD grant \\sub.domain.com\group\folder 'domain\Domain Admins:RX'`

Comment: If I try this:`.\dfsutil property SD grant \\sub.domain.com\group\folder "'domain\Domain Admins':RX"` I get the follwowing error: "Could not complete the command successfully.
SYSTEM ERROR - No mapping between account names and security IDs was done."